# Как сделать respawn для объекта в unity?

Tags: unity3d

Я хочу сделать шутер где игрок может подбирать патроны, здоровье и т.д. сделал так что бы объект который подобрал игрок пропадал и появлялся заново но он только пропадает но не появляется. Вот код:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ToggleObjectOnTouch : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isTouched = false;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player") && !isTouched)
        {
            isTouched = true;
            ToggleVisibility(false);
            Invoke("ToggleVisibility", 1f); // Ждем 1 секунду перед включением видимости снова
        }
    }

    private void ToggleVisibility(bool isVisible = true)
    {
        Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        if (renderer != null)
        {
            renderer.enabled = isVisible;
        }

        isTouched = !isVisible;
    }
}
```